# How many lines contain the string “int” and do not contain "integer" .h files?

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say you are in a directory that contain some .h files (but not only) and also contain some sub-directories that also contain some .h file.

I would like to know how with a **bash command** how many lines contain the string “int” and do not contain "integer"  in all .h files (include in all sub-directories?

I tried :

```
find . -type f -name "*.h"  -exec grep -c "int" -exec grep -Vc "integer" {} \;
```

But i don't get the good answer... any suggest?

Comment: `grep "int[^e]"`?

Comment: another: `grep '\<int\>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -type f -name "*.h"  -exec grep "int"  {} \; | grep -v integer | wc -l`

This runs `grep` without -c to find all lines that contain `int` then pipes that to `grep -v integer` which cuts out all the lines with `integer`.

Finally, all those lines are passed to `wc` which will count the number of lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in `int` as a *whole word*:

```
find ... -exec grep -Fw int {} +
```

where: `-F` is matching with fixed strings, not regexes; and `-w` whole word matching (so you don't match "hint" or "winter" or, yes, "integer")